# Did Sita Mata posess Siddhis/Riddhis

Tags: ramayana, hanuman, sita, hanuman-chalisa

Did Sita Mata possess the eight siddhis and nine riddhis, which she gave as a boon to Lord hanuman (as noted in Hanuman Chalisa)?

If she did possess, then why did she not escape from the hands of Ravana? Is it like she used them, and replaced herself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not mentioned in Valmiki Ramayana, that Sita maata possessed siddhis.

But Sita maata makes this statement to Ravana in the Sundarakanda -

> असंदेशात्तु रामस्य तपसश्चानुपालनात् |
> न त्वां कुर्मि दशग्रीव भस्म भस्मार्हतेजसा || 5.20.20 Critical Edition

> "O Ravana! Although you are suited to be burnt into ashes, **not having the mandate of Rama and preserving austerity, I am not reducing you into ashes with my glory.**"

This may be taken as a hint that Sita maata had the ability to kill Ravana.

Answer (score 2):

Valmiki Ramayan does not show that Sita possessed any Siddhis/riddhis. However, she is shown to have followed her dharma without fail, and she pray to Agni to protect Hanuman when she learnt that his tail was set on fire. She also issues the below prayer to Hanuman in Sundara Kaand -

> *tvam asmin kaarya niryoge pramaaNam hair sattama 
>
> hanuman yatnamaasthaaya dukha kshaya karo bhavaa!*

Meaning: You are the living-proof of an acheiver of all desired acts, please destroy this sorrow of mine, o Hanuman!

There are 3 individuals in Valmiki Ramayan, who do 'Jai' 'Jai's to Hanuman, Sri Ram in Kishkinda Kaand, with Lakshman also by his side and then Sita in Sundara Kaanda. Hence you have the Hindi verse used in Bhajanas -

> Raam Lakshman Jaanaki 
> Jai bole Hanumaan ki!!